# How to resample data with bounds for each group?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a lot of data about two variables Var1 and Var2 in different contexts (space & time) that I want to look in regular time intervals (this time interval depends on the name) with a constant frequency (let's say 1 second).

Here is my dataframe :

```
Name    Date          DatetimeUtc         Var1 Var2     StartTimeWanted EndTimeWanted      
Zeus 2018-01-02 2018-01-02 16:20:00.0840  1.0  2.5  2018-01-02 16:20:00   2018-01-02 16:30:00
Zeus 2018-01-04 2018-01-04 16:20:01.1470  0.1  1.7  2018-01-04 16:20:00   2018-01-04 16:30:00
Zeus 2018-01-04 2018-01-04 16:20:01.1490  1.4  0.1  2018-01-04 16:20:00   2018-01-04 16:30:00
Zeus 2018-01-04 2018-01-04 16:28:00.0010  1.4  2.9  2018-01-04 16:20:00   2018-01-04 16:30:00
....
Iris 2018-01-02 2018-01-02 16:21:32.0840  1.2  4.1  2018-01-02 16:00:00   2018-01-02 16:45:00
Iris 2018-01-06 2018-01-06 16:22:00.5487  4.1  0.1  2018-01-06 16:00:00   2018-01-06 16:45:00
Iris 2018-01-06 2018-01-06 16:22:00.9784  4.5  4.1  2018-01-06 16:00:00   2018-01-06 16:45:00
....
```

I would like the following output :

```
Name     Date     BucketID  AverageVar1 AverageVar2
Zeus  2018-01-02  16:20:00     1.0         2.5
Zeus  2018-01-02  16:20:01     NaN         NaN
Zeus  2018-01-02  16:20:02     NaN         NaN
...
Zeus  2018-01-02  16:29:59     NaN         NaN
Zeus  2018-01-04  16:20:00     NaN         NaN
Zeus  2018-01-04  16:20:01     0.75        0.9
...
Zeus  2018-01-04  16:28:00     1.4         2.9
...
Zeus  2018-01-04  16:29:59     NaN         NaN
Iris  2018-01-02  16:00:00     NaN         NaN
Iris  2018-01-02  16:00:01     NaN         NaN
...
Iris  2018-01-02  16:21:32     1.2         4.1
...
Iris  2018-01-02  16:44:59     NaN         NaN
Iris  2018-01-06  16:00:00     NaN         NaN
...
Iris  2018-01-06  16:22:00     4.3         2.1
Iris  2018-01-06  16:22:01     NaN         NaN
...
Iris  2018-01-06  16:44:59     NaN         NaN
```

And ideally I would like to replace the NaN by the most recent values when it is possible :

```
Name     Date     BucketID  AverageVar1 AverageVar2
Zeus  2018-01-02  16:20:00     1.0         2.5
Zeus  2018-01-02  16:20:01     1.0         2.5
Zeus  2018-01-02  16:20:02     1.0         2.5
...
Zeus  2018-01-02  16:29:59     1.0         2.5
Zeus  2018-01-04  16:20:00     NaN         NaN
Zeus  2018-01-04  16:20:01     0.75        0.9
...
Zeus  2018-01-04  16:28:00     1.4         2.9
...
Zeus  2018-01-04  16:29:59     1.4         2.9
Iris  2018-01-02  16:00:00     NaN         NaN
Iris  2018-01-02  16:00:01     NaN         NaN
...
Iris  2018-01-02  16:21:32     1.2         4.1
...
Iris  2018-01-02  16:44:59     1.2         4.1
Iris  2018-01-06  16:00:00     NaN         NaN
...
Iris  2018-01-06  16:22:00     4.3         2.1
Iris  2018-01-06  16:22:01     4.3         2.1
...
Iris  2018-01-06  16:44:59     4.3         2.1
```

NB : I would like to use only vectorized functions and not loops because the volume of data is very high.

I have tried :

```py
data_frame.set_index("DatetimeUtc").groupby(["Name", "Date", pd.Grouper(key="DatetimeUtc", freq="1s")])["Var1", "Var2"].mean().fillna(method="bfill").reset_index()
```

This works quite well but the BucketID starts at the first DatetimeUtc of the group and not the StartTimeWanted. Same for the end... But there is a big problem : buckets are not created when there is no data around (in other words, there are no NaN in the output).

So I tried :

```py
data_frame.set_index("DatetimeUtc").groupby(["Name", "Date"])["Var1", "Var2"].resample("1s").mean().fillna(method="bfill").reset_index()
```

And it solves the problem of the buckets not created when there is no data around (now I have the NaN as I wanted).

However, I still have a problem to force the resample to start at StartTimeWanted and to end at EndTimeWanted. I don't have any idea how to use these values. I have partially solved the problem for EndTimeWanted by dropping the data where the BucketID is after the EndTimeWanted. But the creation of buckets between StartTimeWanted and my first datetime for each group seems more complicated...

Comment: That looks like an interesting question, but... can't you break it down further? That's a lot to ingest.

Comment: Yes sorry... To keep it simple, I have a timestamped data that I would like to groupby and resample between two bounds (16:00:00 and 16:30:00 for example), knowing that these two bounds depend on the group.